# Erro ao retornar model com Entity

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

Estou tentando retornar Model que possui uma outra Model dentro porem nao só gero o erro(ler final)

-Minha Controller

```
 [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IEnumerable<CidadeModel> Get(int id)
        {
            //return new CidadeDAL().buscar_Cidade(id);
            var list = _context.Cidade.Where(cidade => cidade.ID == id);
            return list;
       }
```

-minha Model

```
public class CidadeModel
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public EstadoModel id_Estado { get; set; }
        public int IBGE { get; set; }
    }
```

- DataContext

```
public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) { }
        public DbSet<CidadeModel> Cidade { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EstadoModel> Estado { get; set; }

        #region Required
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<CidadeModel>()
               .HasOne(c => c.id_Estado)
               .WithOne()
               ;

        }
        #endregion
```

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'Id_EstadoID'.
Invalid column name 'Id_EstadoID'.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Você esta tentando obter uma "tabela" inteira usando a model estado no banco, para obter essas informações, tem que usar um parâmetro de busca no banco relacionado a essa tabela, vou deixar uma exemplo aqui em baixo utilizando o Id do estado.

- Model

`public class CidadeModel` 
`{`
    `public int ID { get; set; }`
    `public string Nome { get; set; }`
    `public int EstadoId{ get; set; }`
    `public int IBGE { get; set; }` 
    `public EstadoModel Estado { get; set; }`
`}`

- Relacionar o item

`protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)`
`{`
    `modelBuilder.Entity<CidadeModel>()`
     `.HasOne(c => c.Estado)`
    `.WithMany(y = y.CidadeModel)`
    `.HasForeignKey(x => x.EstadoId);`
`}`

Ou se preferir deixe o Entity fazer a relação pelas model

`protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)`
`{`
    `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);`
`}`

- Acessar os dados do estado

`[HttpGet("{id}")]`
`public IEnumerable<CidadeModel> Get(int id)`
`{`
    `var list = _context.Cidade.Where(cidade => cidade.ID == id).Include(e => e.Estados);`
    `return list;`
`}`

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).